# Android Emulator for Visual Studio 2015 not launching

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

I was working on an app for Android platform using Android Studio in the beginning but then I switched to Visual Studio + Xamarin because I was more proficient in C# and XAML. Now, when I try to build, the emulator doesn't come on. I tried Cross Platform and Android app, and the same thing happens. The bar at the bottom goes half way and stalls. It stays there for as long as 45 minutes. No error message is thrown. I removed Android Studio and Genymotion thinking it may be causing the issue, but it still persists. I'd hate to remove VS and Xamarin, so other than that, is there anything you can suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things to try to narrow down the problem:

1. Make sure the Android project is set as your Startup Project and “deploy” is ticked under Build > Configuration Manager
2. Check that you’re running Visual Studio as Administrator
3. Verify that the Xamarin installation is on the latest Stable: Tools > Options > Xamarin > Other > “Check Now”
4. Hyper-V needs to be enabled for the Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Android emulator. Use this guide to make sure things are set up correctly https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/
5. Look for specific errors in diagnostic information https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Getting_Diagnostic_Information